# Pyomo - is it possible to define conditional domains on a variable set?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, pyomo

I want to define an array of variables `x`, where some will be integer variables and some real (continuous) variables. For instance, I have three sets:

```
model    = pyo.AbstractModel()
model.N  = pyo.Set()
model.NL = pyo.Set()
model.NN = pyo.Set()
```

`NL` and `NN` are mutually exclusive sets whose union is `N`.

I would like to define the following variables:

```
model.x = pyo.Var(model.N, within = pyo.Integers) # if x in NL
model.x = pyo.Var(model.N, within = pyo.Reals)    # if x in NN
```

I can of course rename `xL` and `xN`, but is it possible to have a single variable set `x` with subset dependent domains?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think you can subdivide the domain of 1 variable.  This seems like a very odd situation.  If you know all of the set relationships, why don't you just make two variables, one indexed by each of the exclusive sets?  Having a variable with a partial domain in integers and another part in reals ... seems like a good clue to re-formulate.

Comment: Mathematically within the model it makes sense. `x` is the number of shares being allocated to assets in set `N`. Some assets require the number of shares to be integer (like regular stocks) while others allow fractional values (like Bitcoin). Yes I could easily create a model where `xL` is number of shares in stocks and `xN` in cryptocurrency, but the mathematical description of the model is much cleaner if you use just `x` for the entire set `N`. 

Since Pyomo is about making the model "readable", I was curious whether or not I need to use a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There are several ways to accomplish this:

1. The `domain` (or `within`) argument can take a rule:

   ```py
   def x_domain(m, i):
       if i in m.NL:
           return pyo.Integers
      else:
           return pyo.Reals
   model.x = pyo.Var(model.N, within=x_domain)
   ```
2. You can set the Var to one domain and then update the domain after the fact:

   ```py
   model.x = pyo.Var(model.N, within=Reals)
   for i in model.NL:
       model.x[i].domain = Integers
   ```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Since I use an abstract model I defined the function.